# Angular: How to both word wrap and line break a long div string

Tags: css, angular

I have an Ionic/Angular application where I read in a log file where each message is separated by a line feed (eg `\r\n` for Windows)

I have a simple example of this [on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kqngwg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

What I want to do is

**1.** Wrap any strings that are too long for the view's width **AND**

**2.** Break at the \r\n

To do **1**, I can use (in app.component.css)

```
#messages {   
  word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

To do **2** I can use

```
#messages {   
   white-space: pre;
}
```

But, they do not work together. If I have

```
 #messages {   
   white-space: pre;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I do not get the word wrap.

I tried using a `<br>` instead of the linefeed (I could programmatically change linefeeds with `<br>`s, but this did not work either (it just displays the `<br>`)

Is there any way to both word wrap and have the string break at line feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` to prevent displays the raw `<br>` tag.

```
<div id='messages' [innerHTML]=messages></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap` or `white-space: pre-line` and it will work as expected.

`pre-wrap`

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

`pre-line`

> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

So

```
#messages {   
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou this also works. Really we have two answers here.